# How to redirect output to different directory in BASH?

Tags: bash, unix

I have 3 directories named: /home/user/control4 , /home/user/control8 ,/home/user/control16

I have written a script file which has two loops , the first one is running a simulation, producing 3 files named cc1.txt cc2.txt, and cc3.txt and a second loop is for the names of directory

I like to direct cc1.txt, cc2.txt, cc3.txt to /home/user/control4,/home/user/control8 ,/home/user/control16, respectively. What is the exact syntax for doing this in BASH?

Thanks for your help.

My script file look likes this

```
#!/user/bin/bash
for j in $(4 8 16 ) # loop for directories
do
for i in $(seq 1 3) # loop for simulations  
do
.... produce cc1.txt cc2.txt cc3.txt 
done
```

How to output the three files to the respective directories? something like /home/user/control$j/cc$i.txt?

done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for j in /home/user/control{4,8,16}
do
    for i in cc{1,2,3}.txt
    do
        produce "$j/$i"
    done
done
```

That will produce nine files. If you want one file per directory for a total of three files, some math might do the trick.

```
for i in {1..3}
do
    produce "/home/user/control$((2*2**i))/cc$i.txt"
done
```

Comment: Dear Dennis- Your second answer is closer what I was looking for. The previous answer will produce 9 files, indeed. Cheers- Are your guys sleep at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
cat cc$i.txt > /home/user/control$j/cc$i.txt
```

Comment: Right, I forgot cat - Is it control$j rather than control/$j? Cheers Andreas

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your script right, you'll end up with 9 files: cc1 through 3 each in directories control4, 8, and 16. However, your text description implies that you want only 3 files total: control4/cc1.txt, control8/cc2.txt, and control16/cc3.txt.

If you literally have a command named `produce` that takes output files as parameters, and you only want 3 files total, I'd just specify the three output directories & files manually, and not worry about looping.

If you literally have a command named `produce` that takes output files as parameters, and you want 9 files total, then yes, control$j/cc$i.txt will do that.

If you don't have a command named `produce` that takes output files as parameters (i.e., that line in your code sample was psuedo-code), and the command that produces data just dumps those files out without you specifying anything, then I think you'll have to `mv cc1.txt control4 ; mv cc2.txt control8 ; mv cc3.txt control16` after it is done.